# Apply getDownloadURL() on every image in image collection with ee.ImageCollection().map()

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to download each image of image collection using earth engine java script.
Here is my code.

```
var S2_images=ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR").filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate('2020-06-04','2020-06-11').select(['B2'])

var downloadArgs = {
  name: 'ee_image',
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 10,
  region: geometry
};

var urllist=S2_images.map(function(img){
  return img.getDownloadURL(downloadArgs)
})
```

I don't understand why gives me this error.

> Line 12: Unknown variable references: []

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/00c1ad626dbb69f718392b3c942adb59

Comment: Hi, You are trying to get download URLS inside a .map() function. I'm assuming you get problems with this approach because you are trying print download URLS to your console inside a map() function. I think you have to use a different approach: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting

Comment: Hi, I want to use export in earth engine app. can i use that?